# How to get your own phone number in Android

Tags: android, sim-card

I am trying to develop an application that needs the phone number of SIM Card every time a new SIM Card is inserted in the phone....Then i will use that phone number to get the user subscribed to an online server.I have read many forums and found something like this

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

but everyone said that this is not an efficient method.If this is not an efficient method then which is the efficient method and also I cannot use any other property like SIM id or Subscriber ID etc.I only need the PHONE NUMBER. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this method would not always return right SIM number; it depends on the SIM card itself.
If you really want to get the SIM number, you can send a SMS to a specific phone, so you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

> TelephonyManager is not the right Solution,Because in some cases the
>   number is not stored in the SIM, Due to my suggestion,You should use
>   Shared Preference to store user's Phone number first time the
>   application is open, and after that the number will used whenever you
>   need in application.
>   Thank you.